# Flying Saucer: Convert html to pdf taking a long time and images not rendered

Tags: java, pdf, flying-saucer

I used Flying Saucer library to convert html to pdf. It used to work fine then suddenly one day the conversion failed to render any image in the output pdf file. Below is the method I used to convert html to pdf:

```
public static void convertHtml2Pdf(String htmlPath, String pdfPath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, com.lowagie.text.DocumentException {

    final ITextRenderer iTextRenderer = new ITextRenderer();


    iTextRenderer.setDocument(htmlPath);
    iTextRenderer.layout();

    /** The generated pdf will be written to the file. */
    final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =
                new FileOutputStream(new File(pdfPath));

    /** Creating the pdf */
    iTextRenderer.createPDF(fileOutputStream);

    fileOutputStream.close();
}
```

My investigation has shown that the code is stuck at iTextRendered.layout() forever. Does anyone encounter this issue before and have any idea how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: This issue has been fixed. When I replaced the domain name with IP addresses, the pdf is generated successfully with images. It turned out that the images were not resolved though domain names so we modify the server settings to fix this. 

Another thing to take note is that your html should not contain any reserved character like &. Otherwise, Flying saucer will throw an error while converting from html to pdf. If you generate the html from freemarker template, then you should escape html the fields with ?html. For example, name?html will render any & in name as &amp;.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to tackle the underlying name resolution problem.  Using the IP addresses works out for testing things, though.  Since so many developers are moving things to virtual servers you can't afford to keep hard-coded addresses in a production system.